# Using SharePoint Rest API

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to read SharePoint lists using the following endpoint (http://url/_api/web/lists) and I am passing the access token, but the response returns Access Denied.

While I use the same access token to call an endpoint from the graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists) and it works fine.

Should I use a different access token when I work with SharePoint REST APIs? or am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use a different access token since the endpoints are different. The graph api and sharepoint api are different resource, you need to grant the application different permissions.

[image]

**Note:**

> SharePoint APIs are available via the Microsoft Graph API.  You may
>   want to consider using Microsoft Graph instead.

Comment: How can I get the access token for SharePoint APIs using this URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token - what grant_type should I use? I read something about including a parameter called "resource" which I tried in different formats with no success

Comment: Also, the graph API does not allow me to create a site. this functionality available only in the SharePoint REST APIs

Comment: @OdayHazeem You are using v2.0 endpoint, so you should use `scope` instead of `resource`. It depends on you which grant_type to use, you can use the same one as you get the token before.

Comment: I tried to include the SharePoint APIs read permission for all sites in the scope: scope=user.read AllSites.Read and it gives me the following error ("[AppName] asked for scope AllSites.Read that does not exist on the resource")

Any idea what may have gone wrong here?

Comment: @OdayHazeem Have you added this permission for your application in Azure portal?

Comment: Sure, the permission has been added.